# Fail react-native run-android in 0.60.0

Tags: react-native

When I use react-native run-android command Metro server start. But after few seconds later its getting closed. Do we need to run it by an other command or its a bug in react native 0.60.0 version. Looking for help

Comment: can u share your npm/expo version and other details

Comment: "react": "16.8.6"
 "react-native": "0.60.0"
npm version = 5.6.0

Answer (score 0):

There's probably an error somewhere in your code, which is causing the Metro Server crash.

Just before it crashes, it will output an error log. You can then, follow the log to resolve the error. To keep the cmd window open, follow these steps:

1. Press `Windows key + R`.
2. Type `cmd /k` in the dialog box that opens.
3. Run `react-native run-android`.

Now the cmd window will stay open when the server crashes. You can look at the error log at the end and debug.

Hope this helps you and feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: There is no error log. It just close. And I am using fresh react native project

Comment: @sd_dewasurendra can you share a screenshot just when it crashes?

Answer (score 0):

run-android not working in new version

> 0.60.0

now you can use

```
react-native start
```

**OR**

> npm start

Command is Work